# C - New with structs

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out how to use struct but this code gives me a lot of errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct date
    {
        int today       =   6;
        int tomorrow    =   7;
        int threeDays   =   8;
    };

    struct date date;

    printf("%d", date.today);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you need a struct?

Comment: You cant have the `= x` in the struct definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct date
{
    int today       =   6;
    int tomorrow    =   7;
    int threeDays   =   8;
};

struct date date;
```

You cannot assign a default value to a structure type.

What you can do is to initialize an object of a structure type with the correct values:

```
struct date
{
    int today;
    int tomorrow;
    int threeDays;
};

struct date date = {6, 7, 8};
```

Answer (score -4):

You can't define a struct within a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date { int today, tomorrow, threeDays; };

int main(void)
{
    struct date adate = { 6, 7, 8 };

    printf("%d", adate.today);
}
```

Comment: Sure you can. Try it.